# htaccess 404 loop - internal server error

Tags: html, .htaccess, internal-server-error

I am a newbie here, made an htaccess with 301 redirect pages with extension (.html) to have no extension. The thing is that when entering into a wrong directory path the 404.html page doesn't work probably because a loop: It displays an error

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@pesto.com.uy to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

The htaccess file is as follow:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewrited
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404
ErrorDocument 500 /404
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Warm regards guys

Comment: Have you tried commenting the `ErrorDocument` lines to see if the 500 problem disappears? Basically what I can deduce from your .htaccess is that you want `section` to rewrite `section.html` and from the following rules, the error document 404 would have to redirect to /404 which would be 404.html. Have you tried doing something like `ErrorDocument 404 404.html`?

Comment: Yes, specify your ErrorDocument with the _proper_ file name. No one gets to see that from the outside anyway, so “removing the extension” does not even make much sense for that.